# How to handle file locations when distributing through PyPi?

Tags: python, unix, logging, pid, pypi

The background to my question is this: I've created a small python application (only for unix-like OSs) to create and manage a daemon process. This daemon needs a log file and a pid file. I also have a unix domain socket that I use for IPC. I plan on uploading this application to PyPi to share with other users.

I have three things that I need to know where and how to place:

- Unix domain socket
- Log file
- Pid file

Now I know that I should be putting the UDS and the pid file in /var/run, however, I'm not sure where to place the log file (or should it be optional?).

Furthermore, when distributing my application through PyPi, is it safe to assume all/most unix-like operating systems have a /var/run? Should I literally hardcode the path to the proper file location? Or is there a safer/more portable way of designating file locations?

Answer (score 0):

Only user `root` has write-access to `/var/run/`. Are you going to limit installation only for sysadmins? In that case you better not use PyPI but publish distribution specific installation packages (deb or rpm). There a re many ways to create such packages from Python: `bdist_rpm`, [stdeb](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/), [pyp2rpm](https://pypi.org/project/pyp2rpm/), [pypi2rpm](https://pypi.org/project/pypi2rpm/), [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm).

Comment: My application will have to be run as root regardless since a UDS needs to be created. Nor do I think my project is large/important enough to use specific distribution formats. As a side note, my reasoning is based on [this man page for UDS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) which states, "Creation of a new socket fails if the process does not have write and search (execute) permission on the directory in which the socket is created." My (possibly incorrect) assumption is that when my script is installed, it has no such directory to modify.